# php pdo statement not updaing the table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update the table with the following code but always get `rowcount` to `0` and the table is not updated. The same query updates the table when I use phpmyadmin.

```
$query="UPDATE userprofile SET password=:newpassword WHERE userid=:userid AND password=:oldpassword";
$queryprepare=parent::getPreparedQuery($query);
$queryprepare->bindParam(':newpassword',$newpassword);
$queryprepare->bindParam(':userid',$userid);
$queryprepare->bindParam(':oldpassword',$oldpassword);
$queryprepare->execute();
```

Comment: Considering that PHPMyAdmin cannot do prepared statements, I doubt it's the same query.  Check your variables and make sure they're what you think they are.  There's a 99% chance they're not.

Comment: Actually i was using class variable without refering to  'this'

Comment: you really really should develop code with php's error reporting cranked up to the max. I bet you've wasted many hours by not taking advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert of PDO, but usual an UPDATE with no table modify depend on missing **commit**.

Which DB (and ISAM engine) do you use?

EDIT

looking at PDO manual I found this [post of nils andre with my googelian maily accou](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#108455): about the correct encoding of the connecction. 
I usual set all the chain (html-page, db-connection, db-column-type) with the same enconding (usually UTF-8) to avoid any problem.

In your case if your password contains some "binary" character the **where** will not match, so no update.

Simply remove the old-password condition to verify my hypothesis.

Comment: i am using mysql database and storage engine=innodb